# Access mongodb replica set pod (kubernetes) through another pod AND through external sources

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm running minikube on my local machine, and I can easily connect to my MongoDB pod from both external/internal sources through this setting below WITHOUT the replica set configurations (no startupProbes and no --replSet args)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          args:
            - --replSet
            - rs0
          startupProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - 'mongo --eval "rs.initiate({_id: ''rs0'', members: [{_id: 0, host: ''localhost:27017''}]})"'
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-node-port
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30123
```

If I add those configurations to run MongoDB as a replica set (which is needed in my case), I can only access it externally if I manually port forward using the kubectl command

```
kubectl port-forward (pod-name) 27017:27017
```

I can not access replica sets internally in any way. Only without the replica set flags in the config above.

What am I doing wrong? I've searched thousands of times and can't find any answer to this!

This is what happens when I try to access the services externally without using port-forward:

MongoDB Compass:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

POD trying to connect to the ClusterIp service (Using Prisma through mongodb://mongo-srv:27017):

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     setName: 'rs0',
     maxSetVersion: 1,
     maxElectionId: new ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001"),
     commonWireVersion: 13,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
   },
   code: undefined
 }
```

Comment: I have literally this exact same problem. Did you ever figure this out?